# Finding out if these are partial creations to any sets

Tags: set-identification

I recently purchased a Sterilite box of LEGO at a garage sale and it contained some partial creations.  Some of these look like they may belong to a set while others may be individual creations.  Can anyone help me identify if any of these belong to a set?  And which set?  Thanks!

1. [image: Dark blue and grey partial creation]
2. [image: Blue head minifig]
3. [image: grey and green partial creation]
4. [image: grey partial creation]
5. [image: red and white partial creation]
6. [image: boat-like(?) creation]
7. [image: white blue and yellow partial creation]

Answer (score 5):

- Photo #1 is from [75933: T. Rex Transport](https://brickset.com/sets/75933-1/T-Rex-Transport)
- Photo # 2 and # 7 are from [75170-1 : The Phantom](https://brickset.com/sets/75170-1/The-Phantom)
- #3 is part of [75168: Yoda's Jedi Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/75168-1/Yoda-s-Jedi-Starfighter)
- #5 is part of [75182: Republic Fighter Tank](https://brickset.com/sets/75182-1/Republic-Fighter-Tank)
- #6 is part of [60179: Ambulance Helicopter](https://brickset.com/sets/60179-1/Ambulance-Helicopter)

Comment: Great.  Thanks Syberion for being so helpful!  I know we also have parts of 76078 Hulk v. Red Hulk, 70320 Nexo Knights, 41587 Brickheadz Robin, 60119 City Ferry, 71006 The Simpsons House,  and 75292 Star Wars Disney Razor Crest in the tub we got.  The not-so-fun part for me is going to be going through the tub to try to separate the sets to see if there may possibly be entire sets for our daughter to build.

Comment: @Legosfordaughter thats quite a nice set of pieces from some rather nice sets, The Razorcrest is still on shelves. The Simpsons House is quite iconically The Simpsons House, and the above figure of Admiral Thrawn is getting quite sought after!

Answer (score 2):

#4 looks like part of [75154: TIE Striker](https://brickset.com/sets/75154-1/TIE-Striker):

[image]

Based on the intersection of these lists: [Sets containing Hinge Pl.Top 2X4 W.Ø4.85Hole](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-design-98286/page-1) and [Sets containing Roof Tile 1X2 45° W 1/3 Plate in Sand Blue](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6139519).

The 1x6 black-yellow striped tile is an "aftermarket accessory", as it only appears in [one single set, which is definitely not this one](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-design-38273).